# joomla form markup

Tags: php, joomla

I'm working on the Joomla profile edit form. What I want to do is change the markup used, mostly to add CSS classes. Basically really simple stuff. The thing is, the form fields are processed by Joomla and given out in a loop like this:

```
<?php foreach($this->form->getFieldsets() as $fieldset):?>
  <?php $fields = $this->form->getFieldset($fieldset->name);?>
  <?php foreach($fields as $field):?>
    <?php echo $field->label; ?>
    <?php echo $field->input;?>
  <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Extensions might add their own fields to the loop so the default inputs can't be hard-coded. What I don't know, for instance, is how to add a class to the label of an input. To change input attributes, I've tried using `JForm::setFieldAttribute` but it doesn't seem to have any effect when used from an override. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: The class must be applied at some point before this. Otherwise, how does this loop know which elements to add classes to? Where are the form elements defined?

Comment: @isherwood That is the question. The loop is a simpliefied version from the one included in K2. But if I'm not mistaken it's the default form loop since Joomla 1.6. All field properties are previously defined in the xml files. My question is if I can modify them inside or before the loop, but from this override file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements for the profile plugin are defined in the `profiles/profile.xml` file. To add a class to the input - you can do one of two things. Firstly edit the xml file. The majority of form fields accept a class, for example in the default profile plugin

```
        <field
            name="address1"
            type="text"
            id="address1"
            description="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ADDRESS1_DESC"
            filter="string"
            label="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ADDRESS1_LABEL"
            message="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ADDRESS1_MESSAGE"
            size="30"
            class="custom_class"
        />
```

You can see I've just added class to the end. Note you can also include the form fields without a loop. See the weblinks component (form view) for an example of this. They do it like so:

```
        <div class="formelm">
            <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('address1'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('address1'); ?>
        </div>
```

So you can see `address1` is the name of the field as defined in the xml file - and this just echo's out the relevant data. This is also a perfectly acceptable way to add a class.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This is actually a good solution. However, one needs to know what the fields will be. I'm working on a template and it should work with any field that is added to the website by third party extensions. So what I'd like to do is check the type of field and add classes accordingly.

Comment: Is this solution essentially a "core hack" that may get overwritten with a Joomla update?

Comment: @PapayaGiver I don't think what your doing is natively supported in that case. **As far as I'm aware** those are the only two ways to add a class to a form field.

Comment: @isherwood Yes this is a core hack in a way - the profile plugin is designed to be adapted to whatever - and over 50% of the time you'll find people copy the plugin and all files within to a new name/folder and use this instead with the plugin then having a new name/folder etc. - it will no longer be overwritten with a Joomla! Update. If you're just editing the existing Joomla! Plugin as is - then yes it will be overwritten with a Joomla! Update

Comment: I just found a solution: `<?php $this->form->setFieldAttribute(str_replace('jform_','',$field->id),'class','myclass'); ?>`. This lets you add a class inside the loop. For the label, some regular expressions will do. My problem before was that I didn't get rid of the jform_ prefix.

Comment: Regarding the original solution, I think some xml files can be copied to the overrides. If the system picks it up there would be no problems with updates.